# Why am I getting "bad_cast" with GenServer?

Tags: elixir

New to elixir....So I'm typing *iex server.ex* to start the elixir environment with StackServer.  (I'm using kiex and kerl to setup elixir if that makes a difference).

I do:

```
{:ok, pid} = GenServer.start_link(StackServer, [5, "cat", 9])  #line 1
:ok        = GenServer.cast(pid, {:push, 2}) #line 2
```

*line 1* is fine, but when I do *line 2* above I get the following error:

```
23:50:04.491 [error] GenServer #PID<0.64.0> terminating
** (stop) bad cast: {:push, 2}
    lib/gen_server.ex:432: StackServer.handle_cast/2
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:615: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:681: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: {:"$gen_cast", {:push, 2}}
State: [5, "cat", 9]
```

What does the error mean and what am I doing wrong?

**source code for server.ex**

```
defmodule StackServer do
  use GenServer

  def handle_call(:pop, _from, [last|rest]) do
    {:reply, last, rest}
  end

  def handle_cast({:push, value}, stack) do
    {:noreply, [value|stack]}
  end
end
```

# {:ok, pid} = GenServer.start_link(StackServer, [5, "cat", 9])
   # :ok        = GenServer.cast(pid, {:push, 2})

EDIT:

I'm using elixir 1.1.1 on top of Erlang (SMP,ASYNC_THREADS,HIPE) (BEAM) emulator version 7.2, erlang OTP 18 on Ubuntu Linux 14.04

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of erlang and elixir? Your code works just fine if I paste it into iex.

Comment: Also sometimes helpful to supply more details about the platform you're running on. OS,  version etc.

Comment: @PatrickOscity using 1.1.1 elixir and erl 7.2, erlang OTP 18

Comment: @PatrickOscity, thanks, this appears to be working.  I'm honestly not sure what I was doing before to make it fail

Comment: it's possible I was tired and was using GenServer.call instead of cast, ugh